# Refresh variable when reading from a txt file

Tags: python

I have a file in my python folder called data.txt and i have another file read.py trying to read text from data.txt but when i change something in data.txt my read doesn't show anything new i put

Something else i tried wasn't working and i found something that read, but when i changed it to something that was actually meaningful it didn't print the new text.

Can someone explain why it doesn't refresh, or what i need to do to fix it?

```
with open("data.txt") as f:
    file_content = f.read().rstrip("\n")
    print(file_content)
```

Comment: How is Python supposed to _know_ that you changed the file? When the `with` block is done, the file-handle is gone

Comment: What do you mean: `i change something in data.txt`? How is this change made?

Comment: *it wasn't working* is probably not a good definition of the problem. Please tell what does your file look like, what does it look like after editing, and how do you want it to look like

Comment: the data.txt file had only the content .... and after changes it was

Comment: An important point to note about programming is that *when* some code executes is just as important as *what* that code does. If your code runs once at the start of a program and then `data.txt` changes after that, your program won't know that and `file_content` won't change unless you re-read the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First and foremost, strings are immutable in Python - once you use `file.read()`, that returned object cannot change.

That being said, you must re-read the file at any given point the file contents may change.

For example

read.py

```
def get_contents(filepath):
    with open(filepath) as f:
        return f.read().rstrip("\n")
```

main.py

```
from read import get_contents
import time

print(get_contents("data.txt"))

time.sleep(30)
# .. change file somehow

print(get_contents("data.txt"))
```

Now, you could setup an infinite loop that watches the file's last modification timestamp from the OS, then always have the latest changes, but that seems like a waste of resources unless you have a specific need for that (e.g. tailing a log file), however there are arguably better tools for that

Answer (score 0):

It was unclear from your question if you do the read once or multiple times. So here are steps to do:

1. Make sure you call the read function repeatedly with a certain interval
2. Check if you actually save file after modification
3. Make sure there are no file usage conflicts

So here is a description of each step:

1. When you read a file the way you shared it gets closed, meaning it is read only once, you need to read it multiple times if you want to see changes, so make it with some kind of interval in another thread or async or whatever suits your application best.
2. This step is obvious, remember to hit ctrl+c
3. It may happen that a single file is being accessed by multiple processes, for example your editor and the script, now to prevent errors try the following code:

```py
def read_file(file_name: str):
    while True:
        try:
            with open(file_name) as f:
                return f.read().rstrip("\n")
        except IOError:
            pass
```